# Chat.js, Codeigniter and MySQL. Something wrong on recover data

Tags: codeigniter, chart.js

So, i want to bring data from mysql, and organize by months. Im separating date by months and applying SUM, to SUM the value of all months, and organize on **chart.js**
My problem, is on Chart. Chart is apllying all the result on unique month.
January has so many data, and all of them is going to Feb, for example...

**My controller:**

```
`<?php
 defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

 class start extends CI_Controller {

public function index(){
$this->load->model('Start_class');
$data['janeiro']    = $this->Start_class->janeiro();
$data['fevereiro']  = $this->Start_class->fevereiro();`
```

**My model:**

```
function janeiro(){
$minvalue = '2016-01-01';
$maxvalue = '2016-01-31';

$query1   = $this->db->select('SUM(valorcompra) as valorcompra')->from('compravista')->where("datavencimento BETWEEN '$minvalue' AND '$maxvalue' ")->get();
$retorno = $query1->row()->valorcompra;
return $retorno;
}

function fevereiro(){
$minvalue = '2016-02-01';
$maxvalue = '2016-02-31';

$query2   = $this->db->select('SUM(valorcompra) as valorcompra')->from('compravista')->where("datavencimento BETWEEN '$minvalue' AND '$maxvalue'")->get();
$retorno = $query2->row()->valorcompra;
return $retorno;
}
```

**and my chart:**

```
var data = {
    labels: ["Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julho", "Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro"],
    datasets: [
    {
        label: "Dados primários",
        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
        highlightFill: "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
        highlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",

        data: [<? echo $janeiro ?>, <? echo $fevereiro ?>, randomnb(), randomnb(), randomnb(), randomnb(), randomnb(), randomnb(), randomnb(), randomnb(), randomnb(), randomnb()]
    },
```

Comment: what's error you are getting ?

Comment: In the **model** you have used the `Where` statement wrong. change it to `where("datavencimento BETWEEN '$minvalue' AND '$maxvalue' ",null,false)` in both query.

Comment: Oh, it solved in part! But all the month that are null, dont appears on chart..

Comment: Oh, i solved the problem! thanks man x)

Comment: I have added it as answer please approve it.

Answer (score 0):

In the model you have used the Where statement wrong.

Replace

```
where("datavencimento BETWEEN '$minvalue' AND '$maxvalue' ")
```

to

`where("datavencimento BETWEEN '$minvalue' AND '$maxvalue' ",null,false)`

in both query.